# Top users : Am I not really this week's Top User?

Tags: bug, reputation

Please check the information in

[Leagues](http://stackexchange.com/leagues) [image]

[User Reputation Ranks Windows Phone](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/197/week/windowsphone)[image]

When I checked the Top Users in Stack Exchange's Leagues page, the Windows Phone section showing a person as this week's top user and another one as this month's (both of them are not me!. See first picture). When I click on this section it navigating to User reputation ranks Windows Phone page. But here this week's and this month's Top user is me(N K). Can I get the reason behind this difference?